# How do I change the time from 24h to 12h

Tags: settings, time

I'm new to Linux (Elementary) and I can't seem to change my time from the 24h format to the 12h format which I do understand. Hope you can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the date format in the panel?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/can-i-change-the-date-format-in-the-panel)

Answer (score 3):

Right click your displayed date/time and then click "Date & Time Settings" and then it literally asks if you want 12hr or 24.