# Custom date and time format - Elementary OS 5

Tags: release-hera, settings, time, clock

I used various guides to change the date and time format on the top system bar and I found nothing working. How can I edit the date and time format in elementary os 5? I would like something like that (% d.% M.% Y -% H:% M:% S)

Comment: Try https://petermolnar.net/elementaryos-customize-date-time-in-wingpanel/

Comment: Or try this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/can-i-change-the-date-format-in-the-panel

Comment: Eventually the last option https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-datetime